# Zend_Http_Client timed out

Tags: http, zend-framework

Hey I am using `Zend_Http_Client` to call a php service in a server, but I got an exception related to time out :

```
2012-05-30T13:47:26+02:00 INFO(6): LeomobileMdcms: Requesting callback url  (http://######.nurago.com/mobileRedirect.php?resp=NRGH&annotations=) while updating  (356812045426135) of device with token (BtPhP), in    LeomobileMdcms_UserInformationController::registerdeviceAction

2012-05-30T13:47:41+02:00 ERR(3): LeomobileMdcms: Exception throwed: Unable to Connect to tcp://########.nurago.com:80. Error #110: Connection timed out, in LeomobileMdcms_UserInformationController::registerdeviceAction
```

This snippet is responsible for calling the callback-URL:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($receivedSmsUrl);
$client->setConfig(array("timeout"=>5));
try {
    $this->log("Requesting callback url ($receivedSmsUrl) while updating "
               ."IMEI ($address) of device with token ($token), in ".__METHOD__,
               Zend_Log::INFO);
    $response = $client->request();
    if ($response->isError()) {
        $this->log("Request failed. Server reply: ".$response->getStatus()
                   ." ".$response->getMessage(),
                   Zend_Log::WARN);
    }
} catch(Zend_Http_Client_Exception $e) {
    $this->log("Exception throwed: ".$e->getMessage().", in ".__METHOD__,
               Zend_Log::ERR);
}
```

I was thinking it a firewall issue but unfortunately it is not related to Firewall.

Please can some one help in that ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Adapter from Socket(default) to Curl. This should resolve the issue:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();
$client->setAdapter('Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl');
```

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate more on why the Op should use Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl?  At the very least link to a resource that explains it.

Comment: It helped me, when I faced the same issue

Comment: It save my day.